# Google Web font, font weight changes

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size, google-webfonts

For some reason my google web font in the navigation menu keeps on changing its weight from page to page although I have set it to 700. The CSS for the menu is identical on each page. Could somebody please tell me whats going on as I have never found this before.

For future posterity reasons I shall delete the live link as soon as somebody answers. Thanks!

My CSS is

```
* {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

#menu {
font-weight:700;
display: table;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
top: -20px;
text-align: center;
left: -10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
font-size: 18px;
height: 20px;
z-index: -101;
}
```

Comment: @ DanielNolan **you mentioned** For future posterity reasons I shall delete the live link as soon as somebody answers.  **it is not the proper way, what if other people have same problem, what you have now??** **you need to post the code here, so it will helpful for others in future.**

Comment: Actually, the live link was pretty much required to replicate the problem. It was a site-specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to fix this:

```
body {
background-color: #FFF;
background-image: url(bg.png);
color: #D6D6D6;
font-family: font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

Your font-family declaration is duplicated.

Secondly, your `700` is being overridden by the `#menu li a` class here:

```
#menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: lighter; /*should be changed to 700*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #333;
}
```

Comment: as you are one of very few on here that are helpful could you please take a look at my other question? its been up for a week. its here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469652/menu-distorts-page-on-mobile-devices-and-creates-white-space-on-the-right